# On Button click change the theme of whole application dynamically and store it

Tags: android, themes

I am using Utills class for the theme changing on click of button, there are 8 buttons with image background. Here is my Utills class

```
public class Utills {

public static boolean isPurchsed =true;
private static int sTheme;
public final static int THEME_DEFAULT = 0;
public final static int THEME_ONE = 1;
public final static int THEME_TWO = 2;
public final static int THEME_THREE = 3;
public final static int THEME_FOUR = 4;
public final static int THEME_FIVE = 5;
public final static int THEME_SIX = 6;
public final static int THEME_SEVEN = 7;
/**
 * Set the theme of the Activity, and restart it by creating a new Activity of the same type.
 */
public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
{
    sTheme = theme;
    activity.finish();
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
}
/** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
{
    switch (sTheme)
    {
        default:
        case THEME_DEFAULT:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
            break;
        case THEME_ONE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.MySecondTheme);
            break;
        case THEME_TWO:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.MyThirdTheme);
            break;
        case THEME_THREE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.MyFourthTheme);
            break;
        case THEME_FOUR:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.MyFifthTheme);
            break;
        case THEME_FIVE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.MySixthTheme);
            break;
        case THEME_SIX:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.MySeventhTheme);
            break;
        case THEME_SEVEN:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.MyLastTheme);
            break;
    }
}
```

And here is activity class

```
public class ChangeBackgroundActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button bck1, bck2, bck3, bck4, bck5, bck6,bck7,bck8;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Utills.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_background);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_changebackground);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    bck1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_bck1);
    bck1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utills.changeToTheme(ChangeBackgroundActivity.this, Utills.THEME_DEFAULT);
        }
    });

    bck2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_bck2);
    bck2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utills.changeToTheme(ChangeBackgroundActivity.this, Utills.THEME_ONE);
        }
    });


    bck3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_bck3);
    bck3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utills.changeToTheme(ChangeBackgroundActivity.this, Utills.THEME_TWO);
        }
    });

    bck4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_bck4);
    bck4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utills.changeToTheme(ChangeBackgroundActivity.this, Utills.THEME_THREE);
        }
    });
    bck5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_bck5);
    bck5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utills.changeToTheme(ChangeBackgroundActivity.this, Utills.THEME_FOUR);
        }
    });
    bck6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_bck6);
    bck6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utills.changeToTheme(ChangeBackgroundActivity.this, Utills.THEME_FIVE);
        }
    });
    bck7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_bck7);
    bck7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utills.changeToTheme(ChangeBackgroundActivity.this, Utills.THEME_SIX);
        }
    });
    bck8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_bck8);
    bck8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utills.changeToTheme(ChangeBackgroundActivity.this,Utills.THEME_SEVEN);
        }
    });

}
```

When I close my application and restart it the default theme again set on whole application. 
How to store the theme for application from Utills class, so whenever I close my application and restart it again the selected theme will set for whole application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to persist your theme somewhere. You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for it, for example. Than retreive your theme and set it to Activity before setContentView.

So. you need to add saving to `changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)` and retreiving to `onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)`